# Is the integral of $\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$ divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fractions, infinity

$$ \,(Set\,up)\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x(x+1)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_1^{n} \frac{dx}{x(x+1)}$$

$$ \, (Integrated)\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_1^{n} \frac{1}{x} + \frac{-1}{x+1} $$
$$ \,(Evaluate)\lim_{n\to \infty} [ln{\lvert x\rvert-ln\lvert x+1\rvert]} |_1^{n}$$

After doing some simplification:
$$ = \frac{ln\lvert x\rvert}{ln\lvert x+1|} + ln2 $$

If I were to say the denominator grows faster, then the integral would come out to be $0$, but whether or not I would consider that additional $+1$ significant, I do not know.

I will conclude that this integral is convergent, but I would like to know if I am correct or not. I would like to understand this a little more. I have not delved into series expansion yet. I watched a Khan Academy video earlier, and he hit on a similar point with limit comparisons (or something along those lines) to explain a problem like this.

Bring anything you know (supplemental or not).

Thanks, 
Michael

Comment: It is convergent (compares with $1/x^2$). But throwing around the $\infty$ symbol willy-nilly is more likely to confuse than to illuminate.

Comment: I used log properties to simplify. ln(1)-ln(infty +1) = ln(1)/ln(infty+1) and ln(1) = 0. Is this incorrect? @ParclyTaxel

Comment: There we are: writing things like $\ln(\infty+1)$ is causing you (and the rest of us) confusion. See M. Rozenberg's answer.

Comment: Your question suggests that you are using $\ln(A)-\ln(B)=\frac{\ln(A)}{\ln(B)}$. That is not right. It's $\ln(A)-\ln(B)=\ln\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$.

Comment: I am so sorry. This is the second or third problem I have ever done like this. I do not know the traditional (or correct) way of expressing this all.

Comment: I see. I looked right over that. Thank you so much! @alex.jordan

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\int\limits_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}dx=\int\limits_1^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)dx=\left(\ln{|x|}-\ln(|x+1|\right)_1^{+\infty}=\ln\frac{x}{x+1}|_1^{+\infty}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\ln\frac{x}{x+1}-\ln\frac{1}{2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\ln\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}+\ln2=\ln2.$$ 
Because $-\ln\frac{1}{2}=-\ln2^{-1}=-(-1)\ln2=\ln2.$

Comment: +1 Michael the x $\to \infty $ makes no sense since you changed your answer. $\ln(2)$ is the value of the integral

Comment: @Isham Do you mean that I need to write it with a sing of the integral?

Comment: Maybe as you have writen before is fine like $\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln(\frac x {x+1})=0$

Answer (score 0):

Since for $x\ge 1,$

$$0<\frac{1}{x(1+x)}<\frac{1}{x^2}\,\,\text { and } \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx <\infty,$$

your integral converges by the comparison test.